# Are there any tutorials for Linux-based audio production?

Tags: sound, jack, ardour

I have been searching for a while for Linux based audio production tutorials. All I can find are tool based tutorials. For example I found tutorials on how to use jack, ardour, lmms ..etc. What I need are tutorials that teach professional audio production with opensource/free tools, like those already available for protools and the like.

If any one can guide me to any videos/articles available it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ardour is by far the most professional free and open source audio production tool you will find.  JACK is also going to be an integral part of any audio production environment you set up on Linux.

[This](http://www.flossmanuals.net/ardour/) tutorial will teach you the basics of how to use Ardour and JACK together to record/produce music.  While you might consider this a "tool based" tutorial, I would suggest giving it a chance.  Producing music on a computer is essentially combining the right tools; and this tutorial teaches you how to use the two most powerful open source tools with very simple, practical and easy to follow directions.

The [Linux Musicians](http://linuxmusicians.com/) forum is also a great resource for learning how to create music using open source tools.  I would highly suggest creating an account there and looking around.

[This](http://www.audio-issues.com/) site has some nice basic audio production tutorials. They of course aren't using Linux, but you'll notice that versions of all the plugins they talk about are available in Ardour.

Welcome to the wonderful world of open source audio production and good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I am leaving this question unanswered in hope that someone else would find me the tutorials I need. The point is that I can now use jack and ardour for basic recordings, but I want to learn how to make my recordings more professional .. how to apply effects in an easy way ..etc.

Comment: @thelinuxer glad to help.  Check out [this](http://www.audio-issues.com/) site for some basic audio production tutorials.  They of course aren't using Linux, but you'll notice that versions of all the plugins they talk about are available in Ardour :P.  Basically, if you can use EQ, filters, and compression well you can make some really professional sounding mixes (assuming your recording habits are good--but that site has tips for these too).  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I guess this site is what I am looking for. I will add it to the answer :)